# How to get the value for next table_id_seq (primary_key) in doctrine?

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, primary-key, symfony4

I am working in a project in symfony 4 and the database is in postgresql. There are two methods that update the  database:

**Method 1.** through a python script with plain sql inserts

**Method 2.** through symfony forms

Both these methods write to the same table.

**Scenario A:**

Method 2. adds a row to the table using symfony form (pid - 1)

Method 1. uses python script to add 500 rows (pid sequence reaches 501)

Method 2. Another user tries to add a row and doctrine tries to insert with pid = 2 but it should be "502"

I tried using GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") and "IDENTITY" in the entity definition but that doesn't solve the problem

/* Entity Class definition for the field */

```
/**
  * @ORM\Id()
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue
  * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
  */
  private $id;
```

/* Form submission handler */

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $data =$form->getData();
            $property = new Property();
            $property->setTitle($data['title']);
            $property->setDescription($data['description']);
            $property->setPrice($data['price']);

            $em->persist($property);
            $em->flush();

           return $this->redirectToRoute('property');
    }
```

Possible solutions

- Define the field in entity class in such a way that it automatically gets the next auto_increment value
- Get the next auto_increment value before inserting from form
- Replace postgresql with mysql (if that helps)
- Replace auto_increment with UUID

Please suggest which is the best solution to go with if exists

Comment: AUTO should be using PostgreSQL sequences and those are server side. I don't see how you could be still getting conflicts using this strategy. Maybe try forcing it `@GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")`. Note that by default Doctrine will create sequence that increments by 10, so you will have big gaps with inserts done by clients other than Doctrine.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński I tried that and it still doesnt solve the problem.The script updates database once every two days and the form is accessible at any time.So the script and form should be able to update at the same time as well.The script adds about 1000 rows every time it runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your entity class I think the declaration is not complete for setting automatic value for id from the sequence table. Try this declaration instead. It worked for me

```html
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"default"="nextval('property_id_seq'::regclass)"})
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
 */
private $id;
```

Drop your existing table and update schema from bin/console